# Trying to render raw OpenGL into a QtQuick application, seems that QQuickWindow::setClearBeforeRendering is not working?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt-quick

I'm using Qt 5.4, QtQuick 2.4.

Basically, I'd like to be able to render raw OpenGL into an application written in QtQuick/QML, and I would like to do so while using `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

The main tutorial I have gone through is the (seemingly) pretty standard one, found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html).

However, this tutorial uses a `QQuickView` rather than a `QQmlApplicationEngine` to load the QML UI.  If I change the code to use a `QQmlApplicationEngine`, the GL rendering no longer works, and I really don't understand why.

The code in [this](https://github.com/redmoonlas/QmlExamples/tree/master/QmlSubItemGlRender) GitHub repository promises to draw raw OpenGL into a QtQuick application using QQmlApplicationEngine, and even manages to keep this promise, but it does so by hooking into `QQuickWindow::afterRendering` (see line 79 of `squircle.cpp`).  If this signal/slot connection is changed to hook into `QQuickQindow::beforeRendering`, the GL portion of the scene again appears unrendered.  This is IMO the simplest example that reproduces the issue I am having (except for some boilerplate hanging around).

`QQuickWindow::clearBeforeRendering` appears to (correctly) be set to false (line 86 of the same file).

Am I missing something?

Comment: The sample on GitHub is not working properly - the label 'Hello OpenGL' is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt 5.4 the [`Window.contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentItem-attached-prop) property was introduced and painting of `ApplicationWindow` content area was changed. I used a custom item derived from `QQuickFramebufferObject` to fix it. You can find example on [GitHub](https://github.com/DmitrySokolov/qtquick-opengl-test).

In my example, when the `FBO__` macros is not defined the code from QtQuick Scenegraph OpenGL-under-Qml example is used. And the `setClearBeforeRendering(false)` is not working anymore. I believe `ApplicationWindow` erases the whole window background when GUI rendering occurs. I had an idea to intercept somehow (by `flags` property and event handlers) the erase background event, but still has not performed it. A custom item based on `QQuickFramebufferObject` works fine, but I think it has a memory overhead compared to painting in `QQuickQindow::beforeRendering()`.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem when upgrading to Qt 5.4.  The workaround that I found is to change the background color on the main QML ApplicationWindow item.

Main.qml...

```
ApplicationWindow
{
  id: mainWindow
  width: 800
  height: 600
  color: "black"
```

Putting anything other than "white" in the color property works for me.  For some reason making the background white overrides setClearBeforeRendering(false) when trying to draw with OpenGL in a QQuickItem using the beforeRendering() signal.

It doesn't matter what color you use since you have to clear the background using glClear in your custom OpenGL code anyway and that will be the one that is seen when the drawing is done.

Just don't use white!

I'm assuming this is a bug until someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: Someone should make a bug report for this. Thanks for this quick fix :)